# Are Cosplay-related questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I've just seen a cosplay-related question, which was posted during the definition-phase.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31538/anime-manga/31755#31755

There was a discussion, whether the question would be too objective, but I have an other question: Are cosplay-related questions on-topic in general?

I know, that a cosplay is always manga/anime-related, but isn't it more a question about dressing/photography? I don't know what question could come up, but I think, that cosplay-questions are most likely something like "How should I dress" "What's the best background" (See Photography.SE) ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Some (if not most) of such questions are highly subjective ("what's the best way to...", "should I do X for cosplaying Y", and so on.
- The questions will most likely be about *just the look*, NOT about the character/story. A question about apparel *might be ok* if the question is directly connected to the story. (Example: Kempachi's eye patch and bells in his hair, which have concrete reasons of existence plot-wise). I'm sorry, but I personaly do not want questions like "how do I tie the ribbons in my hair the way Haruhi did on Sundays?". Forgive me this weakness.
- Some of the questions are going to be like "where do I buy X to cosplay Y", or "How do I make X for my cosplay costume of Y".

For questions about how to make a costume/what fabrics or tools to use, something like [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36782/clothing-and-fashion) will be better.

Subjective questions are off-topic on all SE sites.

So, generally speaking I think such questions should be off-topic.

Comment: I agree, they have no place here.

Answer (score 5):

[Similar to my answer about Vocaloid questions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/143/41), I think we have to limit cosplay-related questions to those that stem from the source material themselves.

Questions about character outfits / design in a particular scene is one thing -- like asking about why Lina Inverse's hair changes colors at certain points in Slayers, or what the different rank insignia in FMA are (and what they look like) -- but actual questions about costume design and photography are too subjective and thus outside the scope of this SE.

Comment: Agreed about this. Basically, if the question is about the actual character design (as necessary to pull off a costume), then it'd be appropriate, and is something that can even be divorced from cosplay. But if it's about the actual costume design, assembly, or other components like "how to make a really convincing costume", that's not really our topicality.

Comment: @GraceNote The example you make is on topic, but it's perhaps the only one question we'd welcome and as you said, it would exist even regardless of cosplay.

Answer (score 2):

The Area51 thread had a very interesting link, including [Guidelines for Great Subjective Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

I must say I love that blog post, and I believe if we demand open cosplay questions are allowed only if they fulfill premises described in there, we may get questions we really won't regret.

Thus, I think allowing them conditionally in the FAQ, along with this specific link as to how to phrase them would have a potential of adding to the value of the site.

Of course poorly written questions should be closed presto.