# Can we ask question about AMV?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I want to ask a question about AMV.

For example, "Does anyone know who made this AMV ? I cant find who's the author is"

Comment: idk, it sounds a bit like id request. Even if it's on topic, it probably got a downvote and it's a bit hard to find the maker. But you're free to asked it on our [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe)

Comment: oh you are right, thanks @Darjeeling

Comment: the amount users that usually found online in chat room, usually not that much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We already have some [amv](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amv) and we do accept those kinda questions as well as Senshin explains in [What is our current stance on questions about peripheral anime topics?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2380/1458)

The question you mention however *"Does anyone know who made this AMV? I cant find who's the author is"* most likely wouldn't be a good fit.

Amv creators are fans, they often have barely to no online presence, making answering it both hard, and even further disconnected from the "Otaku" culture to the point I doubt its actually even related still.

But it also touches the infamous [id-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/id-request), which is off-topic.

All together, you can ask questions regarding [amv](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amv)'s, but try to stay clear of ID-requests while you are at it.